# Can i reference a variable in my xcopy path?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
set /p fileToCopy = "File you want to copy: "
set /p destinationFile = "Destination file (On Desktop): "
xcopy c:\users\jordean\desktop\%fileToCopy% c:\users\jordean\desktop\%destinationFile%
pause
```

Why does this not work? Am I using variables incorrectly? First day using command line and batch files.

Comment: remove the spaces around `=`

Comment: Wow so small, good to know, thanks

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before `=`, otherwise it becomes part of the variable name:

```
@echo off
set /P fileToCopy="File you want to copy: "
set /P destinationFile="Destination file (On Desktop): "
xcopy "C:\users\jordean\desktop\%fileToCopy%" "C:\users\jordean\desktop\%destinationFile%"
pause
```

Comment: thanks! What kind of crazy language has spaces as part of the variable name!